# Why are Java extentions in Browsers less secure than JavaScript solutions?

Tags: javascript, java, browser, npapi

I have read that Chrome and Firefox dropped support for NPAPI. As I understand it this was done because Javas security vulnerabilities. My question is: Why are Java extentions in Browsers less secure than JavaScript solutions?

Is it possible to reenable NPAPI support? Which browsers still support NPAPI?

Comment: That should be simple to answer by Google: Java does not run in the browsers context and supports much more than running applets. And all major browsers dropped the NPAPI support - WIkipedia has a list of them

Comment: Java had a single plug-in for applets, and the security model was flawed. No. It is not possible to reenable NPAPI support. It was removed because the security model is flawed. No browsers will continue to support NPAPI.